# Why can 'Others' read files by default in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to figure out why when creating new files and directories in, let's say, the `Documents` folder, they get assigned, by default, the following permissions:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hello world    0 Nov 19 12:17 'New Empty File'
drwxrwxr-x 2 hello world 4.0K Nov 19 12:16 'New Folder'/
```

Shouldn't 'Others' have no access to my files? From what I've read, Ubuntu is by default pretty secure. However, nowhere could I find a rationalization for this behavior. Would appreciate an answer :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The permissions model of Linux means that, even if you are the only user of your computer, you're not the only user on the system. Many services will create their own user account to run under - for example, Apache will usually run under its own dedicated account.

What you will also notice is that your home folder is usually only accessible to your own account - i.e. permissions `700` or `drwx------`. That means that only you can get at your home folder, even if subfolders within that folder have full access.

This combination provides a useful balance. The default permissions allow service accounts to read any files on the system that they might need to, but they can't change anything. Any files which are personal to you should be in your home folder, so a rogue service won't be able to access them.

You might find the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf) a useful read. This outlines the generally expected permissions and functions for Unix/Linux systems, and most distributions will abide by this.

Comment: For me, on `Xubuntu 18.04`, `/home/<home folder>` has `drwxr-xr-x` permissions. Can't then an attacker try to make a user in my group to subvert this rationale?

Comment: If an attacker has a way to create a user "in your group" you have already lost, cause if he can do that, he can just as easily make one in the "root" group / with root rights.

Comment: It might be worth adding a little about `umask` and how the default permissions for new files can be changed, and the caveats of doing that

Comment: @FlorianBach drwxr-xr-x permissions mean any other users on the system can read the files, not just users in your group. This includes other people with non-admin access user accounts on the system.

Comment: As @Macil points out, your home directory is mode 755, *NOT* 700, on Ubuntu. Anybody who wants to can list and traverse it. While certain subdirectories ("Documents", perhaps) might be 700, files and directories created in ~ are world-readable by default. Since quite a few programs make the same **error** that you made of assuming the home directory is private, they don't change the mode on their own files and end up emitting potentially-sensitive world-readable data. Ubuntu sucks.

Comment: What would be the consequences of changing the permissions of the folder $HOME to `drwx------`? Will it crash some specific service or software? I suppose the Ubuntu team made that decision for a reason. If good or bad is not my focus here, just wanting to know if it is safe to "fix" it without consequences. There are lots of trojans/cryptominers nowadays that can login as another user with weak password and read all our data (except some more conservative defaults like the one adopted by the Dropbox folder).

Answer (score 1):

When you create new files and directories, the initial permissions are controlled by your `umask` setting. The application creating the item specifies the maximum permissions (typically `rwxrwxrwx` for directories and executable files, `rw-rw-rw-` for data files), and then the permissions in `umask` are subtracted from this.

So if you want more restrictive permissions, you should set your `umask` to remove the permissions you don't want to grant. The permissions you show come from having `umask  002`, so it just disables `other=write`. If you want to disable `other=read/execute` as well, you should used:

```
umask 007
```

Traditionally, the default `umask 002` comes from the assumption that all the users on a particular system would be a cooperating community (e.g. programmers in the same department of an organization), so there's little reason to prevent other users from reading your files in general. If you have specific files that are more private, you'd give them more restrictive permissions. If the above assumption is inappropriate for the users of your system, you should use a different default umask in the shell startup scripts.

Comment: I've used `umask 007` or `umask 077` for years. This configuration sometimes breaks scripts from open-source packages, which assume that `umask 022` is set.